# Cordova prepare ios command returns 'undefined'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to run `cordova prepare ios` in the command line, so that I can then use Xcode to build my ios app. It simply returns 'undefined'. Usually it doesn't have any console output but the app is prepared correctly. There are multiple developers on this project, and I recently had to fix a few merge conflicts in the `Images.xcassets/launch.launchimage/Contents.json` file, but beyond that I have not touched my cordova configuration stuff. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the output when I run it with the verbose flag. I'd include more code but I'm honestly not sure where to begin looking for the error.

```
$ cordova prepare ios --verbose
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ios"
Calling plugman.prepare for platform "ios"
Preparing ios project
Processing configuration changes for plugins.
Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser',
  'com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics',
  'com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin',
  'com.mobileapptracking.matplugin',
  'com.mobileapptracking.gaidwrapper',
  'com.mobileapptracking.ifawrapper',
  'nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp',
  'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect',
  'com.google.playservices' ]
Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
undefined
```

Comment: Hitting the same problem. In my case, what makes it go away is removing a compiler-flags="-I...." entry from one of my own plugins plugin.xml... but sadly that entry is there for a very good reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually - I believe what was causing the problem in my case was a COMMA in the -I path (".../hxcpp/3,2,81/include") parameter. Seems like a parsing bug...

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue after a git conflict. Had to manually ensure that the merge was correct in the .xcodeproj.

The extra commas didn't seem to affect it though.